# Carousal view with multiple items without databinding

Tags: xaml, data-binding, .net-maui, xamarin.forms.carouselview

How do I set static text as Carousal view items instead of doing data binding? Here in the below code I am trying to have Page 2 appear when the user swipes to the left. This code says **The property `ItemTemplate` is set more than once**

```
    <StackLayout Margin="10">
        <CarouselView>
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Label Text="Page 1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Label Text="Page 2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Since it is static text, can you consider using < carouselview Emptyview > and < carouselview. Emptyviewtemplate > to define the item appearance? I just wanted to ask you first.

Comment: You may define each one in the < ContentPage.Resource > <DataTemplate>, and It is true that only one < CarouselView.ItemTemplate > can be defined in each ContentPage.

Comment: @HongxinSui I am still stuck on adding controls to each Carousal item. I want to add a picker control and Editor control on the first item and then an Editor control on the second and Image picker on the third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the items statically in xaml itself without data binding you can use  [`Array` markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xarray-markup-extension) of type string:

```
   <StackLayout Margin="10">
       <CarouselView>
            <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
                    <sys:String>Page 1</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>Page 2</sys:String>
                </x:Array>
            </CarouselView.ItemsSource>

            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
    </StackLayout>
```

PS: Don't forget to add the required xaml namespace:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Comment: Thanks Cfun. If I need to put in the controls to each view, how would I do that?

Comment: if you mean add more controls, then you just have to  add them inside the `DataTemplate`

Comment: being new to c# and xaml, I am still having trouble getting .net maui controls as a carousal item. Could you post samples please?

Comment: Sample is already in my answer

Comment: If I want to add a control to each carousel item how do I do that?

Comment: Just add the control inside the `ItemTemplate`

Comment: does it answers your question?